# ng model value is not getting cleared

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I hava a ng repeat getting populated dybamically based on some variable

Type

```
                                <div class="clothes-each-tag-wrapper">
                                    <div class="clothes-tag-label relative">
                                        <div class="dropdown-opacity-layer" ng-show="!showDropdownForType">
                                            <span>{{selectedBtmType}}</span>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pointer validate-tag" ng-hide="btmValidatedTags.type == selectedBtmType" ng-click="updateBtmTags('Type',selectedBtmType)"></span>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pointer" ng-click="showDropdownForType = true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select class="ng-select-dropdown" required ng-model="selectedBtmType" ng-change="showDropdownForType = false" ng-init="selected='1'"
                                            name="btnTagForType" id="btnTagForType" ng-options="x for x in tags.Bottom.type"
                                            ng-show="showDropdownForType"></select> </div></div>

<div class="wrapper flex flex-wrap" ng-if="item.Bottom.type != selectedBtmType">   <div class="clothes-each-tag-wrapper"ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags[selectedBtmType]">
    <div class="clothes-tag-label uppercase">
      {{key}}
    </div>
    <div class="clothes-tag-label relative">
      <div class="dropdown-opacity-layer" ng-show="showDropdown1">
        <span>{{someselectedValue}}</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pointer" ng-hide = "btmValidatedTags[key] == someselectedValue" ng-click="updateBtmTags(key,someselectedValue,selectedBtmType)"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pointer" ng-click="showDropdown1 = false"></span>
      </div>
      <select class="ng-select-dropdown" required ng-model='someselectedValue' ng-change="showDropdown1 = true" ng-init="selected='1'"
      name="btnTag2" id="btnTag2" ng-options="x for x in value" ng-show="!showDropdown1"></select>
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

now the problem is, i am using ng model value from the drop down, once it is selected i am storing that variable in ng-model='someselectedValue' and hiding the drop down. after that i am showing that value in a different span.problem is the json i am populating has similar entires.if the ng repeat variable changes based on tags[selectedBtmType] my checkbox should reset. but i can see previous values are being already selected.

example if in the first ng repeat i have a field of types and i select a type.but when i populate the second ng repeat (even if i have a field of types),type should not be preselected

Comment: Where is the check box and the json file in your question ? Can you create a plunkr and share the link ? without these details I am not able to understand your scenario properly. Provide a demo code on plunkr to get a quick resolution

Answer (score 0):

Clear the ng-model of select everytime before populating ,i think this will work ,as it will not have any data to select ,because now the selected value is getting stored in that model,please inform if it works.

you have to use `delete someselectedValue`

Comment: every time ng repeat data is changed how do i delete the someselectedValue. where and how do i trigger it

Comment: you should delete the value on the base of which your checkbox gets selected in first step,before populating your second json

Comment: but i am not able to access someselectedValue outside the ng repeat.because if i try to print someselectedValue outside it doesn't show anything.

Comment: i just edited code and added the top part of the code.(sorry i coun't pretify it).please have a look